# How to make boot with multiple parts move with rig?

Tags: modifiers, rigging, parent, pose-mode

The shoes of my character have multiple objects attached to it that are not parented yet. I'm trying to parent the objects to the shoe so it will move with the rig. I've tried to join (CTRL + J) all objects together and add an armature deform to the shoe but some attachments don't move correctly. I've tried applying the modifiers and parenting the attachments to the shoe then adding an armature deform but I've gotten the same results. Any thoughts? Thanks

File: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e7ebb9a919eb2a0b3758214b1711806520230822091907/f39742a2d8e2abb13e03e7e79f8c701220230822091921/d0b43f

Comment: Yes you can join the boots to the body, apply the Mirror of the boots, make sure that the normals are correctly oriented, shift select the body and Ctrl J, then select the armature in Object mode, shift select the mesh, switch to Weight Paint mode, select the feet and shalves bones and top menu > Weights > Assign Automatic from Bones, and it will need a bit of corrections